# Facing error response from daemon-Windows

Tags: windows, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am trying to run apache Kafka on windows using docker and my docker-compose.yml code is as follows:

```
version: "3"
services:
  spark:
    image: jupyter/pyspark-notebook
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "4010-4109:4010-4109"
    volumes:
      - ./notebooks:/home/jovyan/work/notebooks/
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    container_name: kakfa
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

When I execute the command

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up
```

I get an error: **Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint kafka-spark-1 (452eae1760b7860e3924c0e630943f825a809272760c8aa8bbb2f58ab2865377): Bind for 0.0.0.0:9092 failed: port is already allocated**

I have tried **net stop winnat and net start winnat**, unfortunately this solution didn't work.
Would appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score 0):

Spark isn't running Kafka

Remove the ports here

```
image: jupyter/pyspark-notebook
ports:
  - "9092:9092"
```

---

Also, change variable for Kafka to use the proper hostname, otherwise Spark will not work with it...

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
```

Then you can also remove ports for Kafka container since you wouldn't have access from the host. Unless you [add external listeners](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka#accessing-apache-kafka-with-internal-and-external-clients).

You may also be interested in an [example notebook](https://github.com/OneCricketeer/docker-stacks/blob/master/hadoop-spark/spark-notebooks/kafka-sql.ipynb) I use to test PySpark with Kafka.